# I had this error in my minecraft plugin During startup

Tags: minecraft

When I was starting up my minecraft server after changing my plugin i got this error and when ever I type my command it just says it back in chat
here's the error:https://pastebin.pl/view/7f462b79

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @kwanboi! Please edit your question so that it directly includes you error. Then your question keeps its value even if pastebin.pl goes down. (I am unable to open your link) Have a nice Day!

Answer (score 0):

This error appear when you replace the JAR file of your plugin without restart.

If you just reload, you could have this issue.

So, be sure the plugin is fully compiled and well replaced BEFORE start. If you have this issue, just restart and it should be fine.